# NoMethodError (undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Somebody help me pleases, I sent local server post method  but happened as the above  error so i tried a lot of things recreate table, changed path and model name and so on
However I couldn't slove it ,  I want to know how to fix it and why happed this error,

> Ruby 2.5.3  Rails 6.0.0 rc2

**Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

  def index
    @posts = current_user.posts.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

# Maybe here is happening error

  def create
    if @post = current_user.posts.build(posts_params)
      flash[:success] = "You created post"
      redirect_to @posts
    else
      flash[:failed] = "You failed  posted "
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

private

  def posts_params
    params.require(:posts).permit(:title , :content , :user_id)
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users , :paths => 'users'

  resources :users do
    resources :posts , :except => :edit
  end
  root 'users#index'
end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :authentication_keys => [:name]

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true , length:{maximum: 10}

  has_many :posts
```

*Thanks everyone, It seems to be problem is current_user*

So, I use byebug so that (byebug) current_user
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ↳ (byebug):1:in `create'

**Again thanks everyone, I rewrote code**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :new, :create]



 def index
   @posts = current_user.posts.all
 end

 def new
  @post = Post.new
 end

 def create

   if @post = current_user.posts.create(posts_params)
   flash[:success] = "You created post"
    redirect_to user_posts_path
  else
    flash[:failed] = "You failed  posted "
  end
end

 def edit
 end

def show
end

private
  def posts_params
    params.require(:posts).permit(:title , :content , :user_id)
  end
end
```

Sadly this code also doesn't work ,  just in case , i wrote form code

```
<%= form_with model: @post , url: user_posts_path  ,local: true do |f| %>

<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.label :content %>
<%= f.text_area :content %>

<% f.label :user_id %>
<% f.hidden_field :user_id %>

<%= f.submit  "Create Post" %>
```

Comment: In your **create** method the new post is not created. instead it only "built", but not saved. Also, in create you used `redirect @posts`. but this instance variable is nowhere defined

Comment: Thnaks Matiushkin, i think that i created @posts variable in index action, is this variable is no use ?

Comment: you must be getting current_user as nil.

Comment: it should `redirect_to posts_path`

Comment: Thanks Rakesh , i trying to find with byebug ,  Thanks sk1712 i changed

Comment: Try to remove `only: [:new]` from `before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]`. You definitely need to setup `current_user` if you call code like `current_user.posts`.

Comment: @taro , it would be good if you can remove negative marks from my answer

Comment: Rakesh, sorry how do i remove nagative marks ?

Comment: Hey @taro yamada, I just want to add one more thing to your solution. If the current_user is always the user for a post, you can remove this ```<% f.hidden_field :user_id %>``` from your form, and also remove ```user_id``` from  ```params.require(:posts).permit(:title , :content , :user_id)```. This is because in your create action, you're setting the user with this code ```current_user.posts.create(posts_params)```.

Comment: Hi  Violeta, I appreciate your advice, now I succeed in   create a post

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller, you only require user to login for action `new`. This causes every other page user can visit / interact without authentication.

So, with your controller code, you will get the error `undefined posts for nil` if there's no logged in user with this call `current_user.posts`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

  def index
    @posts = current_user.posts.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    if @post = current_user.posts.build(posts_params)
     # ...
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

To fix this error, you can add more actions requiring user authentication

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
```

or just require it for all actions of the controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in the code:

1. Check user for create action

   ```
   before_action :authenticate_user!, only: %i[new create]
   ```
2. Use create method instead of build method and fix redirect problem.

   ```
   def create
     if @post = current_user.posts.create(posts_params)
       flash[:success] = "You created post"
       redirect_to @post
     else
       flash[:failed] = "You failed  posted"
     end
   end
   ```
3. However, if you get an error, check the devise configuration for `current_user`.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]
end
```

to

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Because you call `current_user` in `index` action, and basically I think all the actions requires user to log in.